# Logitech BRIO complains: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000

Tags: usb, webcam, bandwidth

Whenever I plug in a Logitech BRIO webcam into any USB port on my motherboard, I get the message:

**current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000**

```
usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=085e, bcdDevice= 3.17
usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 2-8: Product: Logitech BRIO
usb 2-8: Found UVC 1.00 device Logitech BRIO (046d:085e)
input: Logitech BRIO as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-8/2-8:1.0/input/input51
usb 2-8: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 24000
usb 2-8: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 32000
usb 2-8: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000
input: Logitech BRIO Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-8/2-8:1.5/0003:046D:085E.0014/input/input52
hid-generic 0003:046D:085E.0014: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech BRIO] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input5
usb 2-8: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000
usb 2-8: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000
usb 2-8: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000
```

Even though the webcam works, I have noticed a low frame rate at high resolutions.

```
# inxi --usb
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 16 rev: 2.0
  Device-1: 1-2:2 info: ASUSTek AURA LED Controller type: HID rev: 2.0
  Device-2: 1-3:3 info: Razer USA RZ01-0321 Gaming Mouse [DeathAdder V2]
    type: Mouse,Keyboard rev: 2.0
  Device-3: 1-4:4 info: Microdia AKKO 3087 type: Keyboard,Mouse rev: 2.0
  Hub-2: 1-13:10 info: Genesys Logic Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.0
  Device-1: 1-13.3:13 info: Arduino SA Turbo LEDz ODO
    type: Abstract (modem),CDC-Data,HID rev: 2.0
  Device-2: 1-13.4:12 info: Arduino SA Turbo LEDz 810c
    type: Abstract (modem),CDC-Data,HID rev: 2.0
  Hub-3: 2-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 9 rev: 3.1
  Device-1: 2-8:7 info: Logitech BRIO Ultra HD Webcam type: Video,Audio,HID
    rev: 3.1
```

lsusb will report this on the device:

```
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
```

OS: Ubuntu 22.10

Kernel: 6.2.2